# How to get latest tag from GIT based on substring

Tags: git

I tags like below

```
 INT_TAG1 // latest tag
 INT_TAG2
 INT_TAG3
 REL_TAG1 
 REL_TAG2
 REL_TAG3
```

How to get latest REL* tag from the above list

I can get the latest tag based on below command:

```
  'git for-each-ref refs/tags --sort=-taggerdate --format=%%"(refname)" --count=1'
```

but here I need the latest tag based on substring REL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `refs/tags/REL*` instead of `refs/tags`.

Comment: Nice. I was trying to cook something with a custom format (`git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=REL*)%(refname:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(else)%(end)" refs/tags`) but to no avail. Excellent solution here.